# How can I read and decode an image with QR code in R programming?

Tags: r, rstudio, qr-code, decoding

How can I read and decode an image with QR code in R programming? **I want to transform an image with QR code in text**.

R has libraries for generating QR codes as 'package qrcode’ and ‘package qrencoder’. But I need one package or another way for decoding QR code from an image JPG or PNG or BMP or another.

Comment: already tried https://github.com/brianwdavis/quadrangle ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following image is a QR code of the url for this page (try it out)

[image]

To read it, as Wimpel points out, you can try the `quadrangle` package, which you can install with

```r
library(devtools)

install_github("brianwdavis/quadrangle", INSTALL_opts = "--no-multiarch")
```

To read the above image, we simply do:

```
library(quadrangle)

result <- qr_scan("https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrADg.png")$values$value
```

And we can see the result is correct:

```r
result
#> [1] "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71592191/how-can-i-read-and-decode-an-image-with-qr-code-in-r-programming/71592356"
```

Comment: Thank you Allan for your answer. But after the execution of the command "qr_scan" appeared the message:

"[C++] Lighten 100% Darken 0% [==========>---------------------------------]  25%  0sError in qr_scan_cpp(mgk, flop = FALSE, lighten = lighten, darken = darken,  : 
  lazy-load database 'C:/Users/Domingos/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/magrittr/R/magrittr.rdb' is corrupt

Comment: @Domingos It looks like you need to reinstall magrittr - `install.packages("magrittr")` first